# How to return 0 for rows which don't exisit

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT `Product`,`Coverlvl`, `Datesold`, Count(*) AS `number` 
FROM Policyinfo 
WHERE `Product` = 'Outbacker-IDOL' && `Coverlvl` ='Gold' && `Datesold` >=
     ('2016-06-01')&& `Datesold` < ('2016-07-01') GROUP BY `Product`, `Coverlvl`
```

It returns data for only one day.  When I need is for the other days in the Month to return 0

[image]

Comment: You need to have a calendar table or generate dates with unions search on this website question is asked before.

Comment: This query is not valid SQL and returns random values for the `Datesold` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Remove groupby because of it you get data for just one entry

```
 SELECT `Product`,`Coverlvl`, `Datesold`, Count(*) AS `number` 
    FROM Policyinfo 
    WHERE `Product` = 'Outbacker-IDOL' && `Coverlvl` ='Gold' && `Datesold` >=
         ('2016-06-01')&& `Datesold` < ('2016-07-01')
```

and for "0" wherever you need this you can use "case" 
example of case is

```
SELECT 
    customerName, state, country
FROM
    customers
ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN state IS NULL THEN country
    ELSE 0
END);
```